# Pygame window displays not responding message

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame
import sys
W,H = 500,500
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))#Display initialisation
pygame.display.set_caption("E")#Display caption
bg = pygame.image.load("scrolltest.png").convert()#bg image
bgWidth, bgHeight = bg.get_rect().size
run = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
def events():
     for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()    
class camera:
    def __init__(self,rel_x,x):
        self.x = 0
        self.rel_x = self.x % bgWidth
        self.scrolling = True
    def scroll(self,x):
        while self.scrolling == True:
            self.x -= 1
    def draw(self,win):
        win.blit(bg,(self.rel_x - bgWidth,0))
camo = camera(0,0)
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    events()
    camo.scroll(0)
    camo.draw(win)
```

This is the full code which is a prototype for a scrolling program it was broken(running nonetheless), However I get the not responding window whenever I tryto click it

Comment: I recommend the following article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 1):

It the method `scroll` of the class `camera` is an endless loop:

> ```py
> class camera:
>    def __init__(self,rel_x,x):
>        self.x = 0
>        self.rel_x = self.x % bgWidth
>        self.scrolling = True
>    def scroll(self,x):
>        while self.scrolling == True:
>            self.x -= 1
>    # [...]
> ```

Note, `self.scrolling` stays `true` and the loop will never terminate.

The method `scroll` is called in the main application loop, so it i snot necessary to implement a loop in `scroll`. It is sufficient to do a selection (`if`) instead of the iteration (`while`):

```py
class camera:
    # [...]

    def scroll(self,x):
        if self.scrolling == True:
            self.x -= 1

    # [...]
```

Furthermore, you've the clear the display by `win.fill(0)` to update the display by `pygame.display.update()`. `self.rel_x` has to be updated, too:

```py
class camera:
    def __init__(self,rel_x,x):
        self.x = 0
        self.rel_x = self.x % bgWidth
        self.scrolling = True
    def scroll(self,x):
        if self.scrolling == True:
            self.x -= 1
            self.rel_x = self.x % bgWidth
    def draw(self,win):
        win.blit(bg,(self.rel_x-bgWidth,0))

camo = camera(0,0)

while run:
    clock.tick()
    events()
    camo.scroll(0)
    win.fill(0)
    camo.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()
```